# Trying to fix mistakes in this TensorFlow code about CIFAR-10 - specially the shape transformation

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow

I'm following [this MNIST tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros) in Tensorflow and making changes to adapt it to run using the CIFAR-10 database.

After running it, I'm getting ~10% of accuracy, and I've read that it's possible to get around 80% of accuracy when using 3 or more convolutional layers, and because my code have this number of layers, I'm trying to understand which mistakes I did. I feel that these shapes transformation I did are probably the biggest mistake here, specially because the MNIST tutorial uses 28x28x1 images, while CIFAR-10 uses 32x32x3 images.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle
import os
from more_itertools import chunked

def unpickle(file):    
    with open(file, 'rb') as fo:
        dict = pickle.load(fo, encoding='bytes')
    return dict

def cifar_array():
    path_file = os.getcwd() + "\\cifar-10-batches-py\\"
    cifar_array = []
    for i in range(5):
        train_batch = unpickle(path_file + "data_batch_" + str(i + 1))
        cifar_array.append(train_batch)

    test_batch = unpickle(path_file + "test_batch")
    cifar_array.append(test_batch)
    return cifar_array

cifar_array = cifar_array()

array_train_images = []
array_train_labels = []
array_test_images = []
array_test_labels = []

for cifar_batch in cifar_array:

    for image in cifar_batch[b'data']:
        if 'training' in str(cifar_batch[b'batch_label']):
            array_train_images.append(image)
        elif 'testing' in str(cifar_batch[b'batch_label']):
            array_test_images.append(image)

    for label in cifar_batch[b'labels']:
        fixed_label = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        fixed_label[label] = 1

        if 'training' in str(cifar_batch[b'batch_label']):
            array_train_labels.append(fixed_label)
        elif 'testing' in str(cifar_batch[b'batch_label']):
            array_test_labels.append(fixed_label)

LEARNING_RATE = 0.01
NUMBER_EPOCHS = 20
BATCH_SIZE = 100

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 3072]) # Total size of 32 x 32 x 3 image
x_reshape = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 32, 32, 3]) # Reshaping to 32 x 32 x 3 matrix
y_real = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10]) # 10 total CIFAR-10 classes

# LAYER 1 - Convolutional, ReLU and Pooling

W1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5, 5, 3, 32], stddev=0.1)) # 32 features of 5 x 5 x 32 size
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[32])) # bias for the 32 features

conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(x_reshape, W1, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME') + b1
relu1 = tf.nn.relu(conv1)
pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(relu1, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

# LAYER 2 - Convolutional, ReLU and Pooling

W2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5, 5, 32, 64], stddev=0.1)) # 64 features of 5 x 5 x 32 size
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[64])) # bias for the 64 features

conv2 = tf.nn.conv2d(pool1, W2, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME') + b2
relu2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2)
pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(relu2, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

# LAYER 3 - Fully Connected Layer

Wfc1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([8 * 8 * 64, 3072], stddev=0.1)) # 64 features were made, and the final size of last layer was 8 x 8
bfc1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[3072])) # 32 x 32 x 3

pool2_flat = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 8 * 8 * 64])
matmult_flat = tf.matmul(pool2_flat, Wfc1) + bfc1
relu_flat = tf.nn.relu(matmult_flat)

# LAYER 4 - Dropout

keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(relu_flat, keep_prob)

# LAYER 5 - Readout

Wrl = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3072, 10], stddev=0.1)) # connecting the 3072 bytes to 10 CIFAR-10 classes
brl = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[10])) # 10 classes

y_calculated = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, Wrl) + brl

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_real, logits=y_calculated))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE).minimize(cost)
prediction = tf.equal(tf.arg_max(y_real, 1), tf.arg_max(y_calculated, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(prediction, tf.float32))

with tf.Session() as session:

    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    # TRAINING

    i = 0
    stop_training = False # Variable used to turn off the training phase while debbugin

    while i < NUMBER_EPOCHS and stop_training == False:
        cost_list = []

        chunked_train_images = list(chunked(array_train_images, BATCH_SIZE))
        chunked_train_labels = list(chunked(array_train_labels, BATCH_SIZE))

        for j in range(len(chunked_train_images)): # the size of images array and labels array are the same
            chunk_images = chunked_train_images[j]
            chunk_labels = chunked_train_labels[j]

            cost_result, _ = session.run([cost, optimizer], feed_dict={x: chunk_images, y_real: chunk_labels, keep_prob: 0.5})
            cost_list.append(cost_result)

        print('Epoch:', '%04d' % (i + 1), 'loss =', '{:.9f}'.format(np.average(cost_list)))

        i+=1

    # TESTING

    chunked_test_images = list(chunked(array_test_images, BATCH_SIZE))
    chunked_test_labels = list(chunked(array_test_labels, BATCH_SIZE))

    accuracy_list = []

    for i in range(len(chunked_test_images)):
        chunk_images = chunked_test_images[i]
        chunk_labels = chunked_test_labels[i]

        calculated_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: chunk_images, y_real: chunk_labels, keep_prob: 1.0})
        accuracy_list.append(calculated_accuracy)
        print(calculated_accuracy)

    print('Average accuracy: ' + str(np.average(accuracy_list)))
```

Is the shape transformation where the problem is? Or there anything else wrong?

Comment: CIFAR10 is stored with the channel first (channel, height, width) - so try reshaping like this: ```x_reshape = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 3, 32, 32])``` then ```x_reshape = tf.transpose(x_reshape, [0, 2, 3, 1])``` to get it back to (height, width, channel) format?

Comment: @AvishkarBhoopchand, I did that, and executed the code after update it with

`x_reshape = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 3, 32, 32]) # Reshaping to 32 x 32 x 3 matrix`
`x_reshape = tf.transpose(x_reshape, [0, 2, 3, 1])`

It didn't change my results, it still give me an average of 10% of accuracy, while the lowest cost value was 2.303514242